# Combining multiple observations across quadrats to estimate relative frequency: how do I account for "unobserved" species?

Tags: chi-squared-test, experiment-design, ecology

I am trying to figure out if/how I can understand if animals are choosing particular plant species for foraging or just using them based on their availability. To do this, I need to characterize the availability of multiple plant species in plots. I have many plots, each one had 8 quadrats (roughly 5% of total plot area), and individuals of each plant species were counted per quadrat. It was not possible to estimate the abundance of plant species in the whole plot, but the plot-scale is relevant for the foraging animals. Observers also walked through the whole plot and recorded presence of any other species that was not detected in the quadrats to gain an overall species list. Now I would like to characterize the relative frequency or abundance of each species at the plot-level to test how their availability compares with how they were used by foraging animals. I have found that the animals often (43% of the time) foraged on species that were not observed in quadrats, and therefore, lack abundance estimates. How can I estimate the availability of those "outsiders"? Here are some ways I have considered:

1. Arbitrarily assign them a low number, assuming that if they were not detected in our quadrats, they were rare. This may bias my results toward preference for these species, especially if they actually are not rare.
2. Throw out observations of animals foraging on these species since I don't have a way of estimating abundance. This may bias my results by removing observations of foraging on (maybe locally) rare species, when there may be a preference there. Also that is a lot of data :'(
3. Some elegant way someone here will suggest for estimating the relative abundance of these outsiders? I keep thinking of detection probabilities and how we might use estimates from other plots to get work this out but ???
4. Find another way to assess the importance of particular plant species to these animals, given that the sampling design for plants clearly missed a lot of species. Maybe a logistic model of plants that were used, and covariates...although relative abundance seems important here too...

My inclination is to go with #4, but I wondered if anyone had a better idea?
Thanks!